# How to calculate effective CSS for a DOM node using PHP

Tags: php, css, domdocument

Given an HTML and a CSS file, how could I calculate which styles are applied to a node? The styles may be applied directly (e.g. #bar) or indirectly (e.g. #foo li)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the applied CSS depends on the position of the node in the tree (e.g. #foo > li applies only to direct descendants of #foo with tagName li), you first have to match each rule in the CSS to the DOM, and then for each node to calculate the resulting CSS, having in mind the weight of each selector.
I'm not sure for the exact formula for calculating CSS weights, but it's something like
`number of #id selectors` * 100 + `number of .class selectors` * 10 + `number of tag selectors`. Of course, you have to mind the inline style and ! importants as well.

For the mapping of CSS to DOM nodes you can use query engine like [phpQuery](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery) or [php-selector](https://github.com/visionmedia/php-selector).

I've wrote proof-of-concept script [php-effective-css](https://github.com/Darhazer/php-effective-css/) which illustrates the first step (mapping CSS to the DOM nodes affected by each rule)

Comment: Actually, the weight calculation you mentioned is a simplification for examples. No amount of class selectors (1, 10, or even 100) will ever outweigh a single ID selector. The simplification makes it clear that one ID selector and one element selector (=101) take priority over 3 class selectors (=030), but the example falls short in case you ever find yourself counting into the double digits. It's just a matter or priority; the selector with the most ID definitions wins. If they are equal, only then do the class selectors matter.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calculating them, you could actually just read the computed styles. This is easily done with Javascript. With PHP you can use [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Here is a ready to use coffeescript for dumping the computed styles of all elements: https://gist.github.com/AndrewO/1841191

There is also already a PHP wrapper for executing phantomJS on the command line

https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs

Hope this helps.